# TDA7575B-based audio amplifier design

Tags: amplifier, audio

I am designing a PCB using the [TDA7575B](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7575b.pdf).

Schematic below.

I have a single input. It is passed through a filter (potentiometers, capacitors and resistors) for tone control and then fed to the TDA7575B.

I am confused about where to connect IN1- and IN2- so I grounded them. Is this connection of IN1- and IN2- correct?

[image]

Comment: Well, let us read the datasheet first: (1) TDA7575B 2 x 75W multifunction dual-bridge power amplifier with integrated digital diagnostics - ST
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7575b.pdf

Comment: Then let us compare the datasheet's Fig 1 block diagram with your schematic. I forgot how to upload my comparison diagram to imgur. So cheat by putting it as an answer.

Comment: Iffi - are we done here now? Do you have anything in my answer that doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You really **do need** to read this section in the [data sheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7575b.pdf): -

[image]

You have the following connections to IN1 and IN2 in your schematic: -

- IN1+ connected to the single ended input drive line
- IN1- floating
- IN2+ connected to the single ended input drive line
- IN2- ground

And this doesn't appear to tally with the data sheet extract above. Maybe you need a TDA7575 example schematic [taken from here](https://citroens-club.ru/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=63643) just to help you figure it out: -

[image]

The big point here is that the inputs are differential and not single ended (as you appear to be thinking of driving them). And, you need those input capacitors for each input. Don't skimp on that because it won't be guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Well, let us read the datasheet first: (1) TDA7575B 2 x 75W multifunction dual-bridge power amplifier with integrated digital diagnostics - ST https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7575b.pdf

(2) Then let us compare the datasheet's Fig 1 block diagram with your schematic. I forgot how to upload my comparison diagram to Imgur. So cheat by putting it as a quick and dirty answer.

[image: tda7575b]

(3) ST7575B is I2C 75W digital power amp, with two channel differential inputs, and two channels 1Ω output.

(4) If you are playing with single channel, I would suggest to short both IN1 and IN2 to signal ground.

(5) And if also want single channel output, Datasheet Section 5.5 also suggests to parallel the two speakers together.

(6) Second part of Section 5.5 also suggests to (a) float IN1, or (b) short to ground.